# Pydev shows Unresolved import but code works

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, pydev

I am using Pydev on Eclipse.

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen
from http.client import RemoteDisconnected

xl_sheet = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
for i in xl_sheet.index:
    web_url = xl_sheet['Web'][i]

    if isinstance(web_url, str):
        if 'http://' not in web_url:
            web_url = 'http://' + web_url
        print(web_url)

        try:
            code = urlopen(web_url).getcode()
        except RemoteDisconnected:
            print('not working')
```

Pydev shows `unresolved import` for `from http.client import RemoteDisconnected` this line. But when I run the code, it works (It prints `not working` for few of the sites that are down). What could be wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that you have two Pythons installed, say a 3.4 and 3.5, and PyDev is configured to check your code against the 3.4 standard library, but you run your code under the 3.5? Because [`RemoteDisconnceted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.RemoteDisconnected) was added in 3.5.

Comment: @abarnert I am using a virtualenv for this project and the interpreter set for this project is the one for that with no external files added to PYTHONPATH. Also, grammar is same as interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding `http.client` to the forced builtins to see if it fixes your problem.

See http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins for details on how to actually do that (and how that's used).

Comment: Nope. It does'nt